# offset.top value different in document ready and console.log() why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset

in my case, my about page is parallax moving well every section when i'm click on about's sub menu (submenu for same page #link). but in my site home page has the same submenu if somebody click on the submenu first goto about page then the exact position. I make it almost done. but offset().top not giving me the exact value. so I stuck.

I console to see offset.top value when document ready..

help me to understand why this happen???

thanks in advance.
sorry for poor english

my site is here http://doitte.com/delatest/

[image: screenshot-]

Comment: Maybe something changed on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because on document ready some of the content may have not got their height. This could be due to resources such as images, font-faces, delayed css/js loading etc.

Instead of using `$(document).ready();` go for `$(window).load();`

Comment: On document ready, the padding and margin will already have been calculated -- the JS does not execute until all CSS files have loaded. You could cite resources such as images, font-faces, delayed (dynamically-injected) css/js etc.