# $(document).ready called before page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Part of index.html page:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">
      <header  class="container-fluid" ng-controller="header">
           <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse no-border dropdown-onhover" role="navigation" id="UNIQE_ID" ng-include="'/nav.html'" />
      </header>
      <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

Then first lines of my javascript:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    var navHeight = $('#UNIQE_ID').offset().top;
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

But then I go to the console and type `$('#UNIQE_ID').offset().top;`, and it works.

Does anyone know how to get this to run after everything is loaded?

Comment: Are you sure that `UNIQUE_ID` doesn't get created after the document is loaded?

Comment: well it looks like it is created after the document is loaded. i put the debugger on that line in chrome and the page is not showing yet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [offset.top value different in document ready and console.log() why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648411/offset-top-value-different-in-document-ready-and-console-log-why)

Comment: ng-cloak might be the culprit here.  The html isn't created until the data is ready.  $(document).ready is only when the browser document is ready.  AnguarlJs might still have some work to do after the page is loaded.

Comment: If you write this code inside of the header controller function, it should work, and you won't need `$(document).ready(..)` at all.

Comment: removing ng-cloak didn't not solve the problem, and changing to window.onload also didn't solve the problem

Comment: I should clarify, are you not writing this code inside your controller?

Comment: Um in my experience it creates less problems to use the jquery selectors when using angular and jquery in a web page so get the measurement using angular.element("#uniqueid").offset().top and don't use the $(document).ready() and put the function inside your controller. That is how it works best in angular. Are you trying to use it for something that can only be done in jquery?

Comment: I am not writing this javascript code in the controller. it's written in a file called header.js  and i have it inserted into my index.html page.

Comment: i had removed both    ng-cloak class="ng-cloak"   and it didn't work still

Comment: Alright I figured it out now. Doesn't really make sense why I have to do it this way but it works. Instead of having the selector on my  <nav> ID I just used  it on the <header> as   var navHeight = $('header').offset().top;

Comment: You should be using angular to make the changes to/get information from the angular elements, not external js like this.